# AWS: Run server-side script via load balancer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have an app server with 3 availability regions, using a load balancer. When I want to access my app's phpmyadmin, I navigate to ***loadbalancer.com/phpmyadmin***.

I have a python script ***myscript.py*** which I want to run without having to SSH into the servers or any such voodoo. I'd like for this script to be accessed by going to ***loadbalancer.com/exmyscript***.

How can I make the url viable? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.To make this URL viable follow this http://wiki.python.org/moin/CgiScripts. You'll have to either put your scripts in a cgi-bin folder or adjust the configuration for your web server.

Comment: Mark my answer correct too if this was what you were looking for.

Comment: I have to wait 10 min